# Is there a way to plot a 2d histogram on x and y axes of a 3d plot in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, mplot3d

In this example by matplotlib: [referencee](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/mplot3d/2dcollections3d.html#sphx-glr-gallery-mplot3d-2dcollections3d-py)

Is there a way to adjust this line:

```
ax.plot(x, y, zs=0, zdir='z', label='curve in (x,y)')
```

to something like:

```
ax.hist2d(x,y, zs=0, zdir='z', label='curve in (x,y)')
```

so that to have a [2d histogram plot](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/scales/power_norm.html#sphx-glr-gallery-scales-power-norm-py) projected an x and y axis of the 3d plot?

Comment: Have a look at https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#bar-plots